# Spring custom view resolver

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-annotations

I've tried to change the prefix of the view based on the useragent.

If the request comes from IE then trying to forward it to "legacy" folder otherwise "modern" folder.

```
@Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        internalResourceViewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        internalResourceViewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

        HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest();

        if(request.getHeader("User-Agent").contains("Internet Explorer")){
                    internalResourceViewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/legacy/");
        } else {
                    internalResourceViewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/modern/");
        }
        return internalResourceViewResolver;
    }
```

Its not at all working. Can anyone suggest?

Comment: Don't use a `ViewResolver` just write a `HandlerInterceptor` and implement that logic in the `postHandle` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't hack around in the `ViewResolver` write a `HandlerInterceptor` instead.

```
public class BrowserPrefixHandlerInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView)
        throws Exception {

        if(request.getHeader("User-Agent").contains("Internet Explorer")){
           modelAndView.setViewName("legacy/" + modelAndView.getViewName());
       } else {
           modelAndView.setViewName("modern/" + modelAndView.getViewName());
       }
    }
}
```

Then register is like a regular interceptor.

```
@Configuration
public YourWebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new BrowserPrefixHandlerInterceptor());
    }
}
```

Just leave the `ViewResolver` alone. This will work for each `ViewResolver` and not just for your own customized version. You might want to make the interceptor a little smarter (check if there is actually a `viewName` and maybe skip it for certain URLs).

Comment: Thank you so much dude. I have tried the same using interceptor.